# Numpy dot product MemoryError for small matrices

Tags: numpy, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I wanted to implement Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) as the collaborative filtering method for recommendation systems. I have this `sparse_matrix`, with rows representing users and columns representing items, and each matrix entry as the user-item rating.

```
>>> type(sparse_matrix)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

First I factorized this matrix using SVD:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
u, s, vt = svds(sparse_matrix.asfptype(), k = 2)
s_diag = np.diag(s)
```

Then I make the prediction by taking the dot product of `u`, `s_diag`, and `vt`:

```
>>> tmp = np.dot(u, s_diag)
>>> pred = np.dot(tmp, vt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

I got an MemoryError. However, I checked the size and memory usage of `tmp` and `vt`:

```
>>> tmp.shape
(686556, 2)
>>> tmp.nbytes
10984896
>>> vt.shape
(2, 85539)
>>> vt.nbytes
1368624
```

which means that `tmp` is around 11MB and `vt` is 1.4MB. But at the time of `np.dot(tmp, vt)`, my system has over 50GB free memory available, which seems sufficient for this computation. So why am I getting this MemoryError? Is there something wrong with my code? Or is `np.dot` super expensive in terms of memory usage?

Comment: `s_diag` is dense.  `tmp` also.  You are combining `tmp` and `vt` on the small 2 dimension.  So `pred` will be a large dense array (686556, 85539)

Comment: @hpaulj do you mean that `pred` will be 686556*85539*8bytes = 470GB, which causes the memory error?

Comment: yes, something like that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this error because np.dot is not able to handle sparse matrices.

As a check, please try converting the matrices to full.

check the sparse documentation  (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)

try:

```
np.dot(u.toarray(), s_diag.toarray())
```

or use

```
u.dot(s_diag)
```

Comment: thx for reply, but `u`, `vt` and `s_diag` are of  `numpy.ndarray` type, which has no attribute `toarray`